# Can I print to two different printers from a browser without the user selecting printer each time?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, chromium, kiosk-mode

We have a web-application and need to print a normal A4 page and a sticker with a custom format. We have 2 different printers for this.

Is there a way to tell the browser what printer each print shoud be executed on?

Having the user change printer each time is not very user friendly.

I'm able to set other properties like margins and orientation using css but cant find anything about selecting the printer itself.